# Libgdx Listener enter and exit fires multiple times

Tags: java, button, libgdx, clicklistener, overlap2d

Im currently trying to implement an clickListener.
I found a great tool with runtime, its called Overlap2D, there i made some nice buttons and loaded them, it all works fine.
Because i wanted to make a "hover" effect for my buttons, i used the ClickListener with the methods enter and exit, it looks so :

```
      @Override
       public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor){

               playButton.setLayerVisibility("MouseOver", true);
               playButton.setLayerVisibility("pressed", false);
               playButton.setLayerVisibility("normal", false);     

               System.out.println("Actor enter : "+fromActor);

       }

       @Override
       public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor){


               playButton.setLayerVisibility("MouseOver", false);
               playButton.setLayerVisibility("pressed", false);
               playButton.setLayerVisibility("normal", true);

               System.out.println("Actor exit : "+toActor);

       }
       @Override
       public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){

               System.out.println("touchdown");

               return true;
       }
        @Override
       public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){

               System.out.println("touchup");

       }
```

And heres the problem, touchdown and touchup are called one time, when i touch down the button or up. But the enter and exit methods are also called during the touchdown and touchupo event O.o that looks so:

```
touchdown
Actor enter : null
Actor exit : Image
Actor enter : Image
touchup
Actor exit : Image
Actor exit : Image
Actor enter : Image
Actor exit : Image
Actor enter : Image
```

I printed the fromActor and toActor also for debugging ^^
And i still dont know why it fires the exit and enter event so much ...
Any one got an idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check the `pointer` that's passed into the `enter` and `exit` methods. If the `pointer` is `-1`, then the mouse cursor just started or stopped hovering over the bounds of the actor. It the `pointer` is not `-1`, then the actor just received a click down or click release (for `enter` and `exit` respectively).

So if you move the cursor over the button and click and then move away, you get two `enter` events and two `exit` events.

- Hover -> entered with pointer -1
- Click down -> entered with pointer 0
- Release click -> exited with pointer 0
- Move cursor away -> exited
  with pointer -1

Also, when using ClickListener, make sure you are calling through to super methods when overriding methods, so it will behave properly!